# Test a React Hook that uses Resize Observer

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks

I created a simple Hook that uses `ResizeObserver` behind the scenes to run a `setState` update every time the element is resized.

It works in the browser, but now the problem that I have is that I have no idea how to write tests for it. I tried `react-testing-library/hooks` but the hook is never called, and I think is because of ResizeObserver.

I tried with Jest, Enzyme, @testing-library but I cannot find a way to really run a test against it.

Basically, in the test, I create a component

```
function Component {
  const [ref, width] = myHook();

  return (
     <div ref={ref}>{width}</div>
  )
}
```

Then I set, for example:

`window.innerWidth = 400` (I tried to resize and call the hook inside the `act` function but nothing). At this point the hook will read the `ref.current.width` and return the `width` value

I expect `value` to change on resize, but it does not. However this exact component, when used in the browser works fine. How can I make sure that `ResizeObserver`  is called? I also imported the polyfill but nothing. Mocking ResizeObserver will make it impossible for me to test the hook and I cannot call the hook outside a React Function! 
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I reached this question while searching for a way to mock ResizeObserver for unit tests. Here is my answer in another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76220429/2528232

Answer (score 3):

`react-testing-library` uses jsdom under the hood to simulate the DOM and it [deliberately doesn't implement layout code](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#unimplemented-parts-of-the-web-platform) like the `ResizeObserver` you want to test. Aside from switching to a testing library like cypress that runs tests in a real browser, you can create a fake `MockResizeObserver` and implement the layout behavior yourself.

You can then use `jest.spyOn` to replace `ResizeObserver` with `MockResizeObserver` for your tests.