# How to mock ResizeObserver to work in unit tests using react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library, window-resize

If anyone can help, I have a custom hook that uses ResizeObserver to change the width of a component. My problem is that when I go to run my units test it breaks all my tests and looking at the snapshot it is not rendering all the elements in the dom. It was working before until I implemented the ResizeObserver. Does anyone know if there is a way I jest.mock the ResizeObserver to not undefined. Or other suggestions.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill';

const useResizeObserver = (ref: { current: any }) => {
    const [dimensions, setDimensions] = React.useState<DOMRectReadOnly>();
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const observeTarget = ref.current;
        const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
            entries.forEach((entry) => {
                setDimensions(entry.contentRect);
            });
        });
        resizeObserver.observe(observeTarget);
        return () => {
            resizeObserver.unobserve(observeTarget);
        };
    }, [ref]);
    return dimensions;
};

export default useResizeObserver;



import { render, screen, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import React from 'react';

import mockFetchProfileActivity from '../../../services/mocks/fetch-profile-activity';
import BarChart from './BarChart';

const component = <BarChart userActivity={mockFetchProfileActivity} />;

describe('Render barElement Chart component', () => {
    const observers: any[] = [];
    let resizeHandler: (observers: any[]) => void;
    (window as any).ResizeObserver = (e: any) => {
        resizeHandler = e;

        return {
            observe(element: any) {
                observers.push(element);
            },
            unobserve(element: any) {
                const i = observers.indexOf(element);
                if (i !== -1) {
                    observers.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        };
    };

    it('Matches the snapshot', () => {
        // resizeHandler(observers);
        const container = render(component);
        expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it('when clicking on a chart barElement drilldown "challenges" are shown', async () => {
        // arrange
        const componentRender = render(component);
        waitFor(() => resizeHandler(observers));

        // act
        const barElement = componentRender.container.querySelector('svg rect');

        if (barElement) userEvent.click(barElement);

        // assert
        expect(screen.getByText('Challenge 1')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had similar issue using Create React App setup.

If that is your case, you can create a file in your root directory called `setupTest.js` and add the following code:

```
  import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
  import 'jest-extended';
    
  jest.mock('./hooks/useResizeObserver', () => () => ({
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        observe: jest.fn(),
        unobserve: jest.fn(),
        disconnect: jest.fn(),
    })),
  }));
```

You can find more information to configure the test environment for Create React App [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/#initializing-test-environment) and the ResizeObserver API [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver)

Comment: That looks fine, the only problem is that I get an error, have you actually got this working this is the error I get.
```Property 'ResizeObserver' does not exist on type 'Global & typeof globalThis'```

Comment: Hi, yes for me is working fine. If I remove the code I get this error `This browser does not support ResizeObserver out of the box. See: https://github.com/react-spring/react-use-measure/#resize-observer-polyfills`. Did you remove the polyfill? As with the code above you wouldn't need it. If that is the case maybe is a version issue. I am using react-scripts 4.0.0

Comment: Sorry just forgot to mention that the error that I'm getting (if I remove the resize observer mock) comes from a library that I am using in my project (@visx/tooltip). In your case the error might be different because you are using different libraries

Comment: I am not using any libraries just a resizeObserver API in a custom hook, as not necessary to use a library. I am using react-scripts 4.0.1 but the error is more a typescript error, not a browser error.

Comment: Ups sorry, the solution proposed above only works in Javascript. I just found an answer that could help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40743131/how-to-prevent-property-does-not-exist-on-type-global-with-jsdom-and-t) What about if instead `global.ResizeObserver = resizeObserverMock;` you add `const globalAny:any = global; globalAny.ResizeObserver = resizeObserverMock;`. Let me know if that works and I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 68):

I've added to setupTests.js/ts next code:

```
global.ResizeObserver = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    observe: jest.fn(),
    unobserve: jest.fn(),
    disconnect: jest.fn(),
}))
```

**Edit:**
Add these lines below the imports above the `describe` method

Comment: That worked for me in stencil js with jest testing. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! this worked for render a component that was using recharts, i was stuck for the entire day, im able to move on thanks to your answer <3

Comment: replacing global with window worked for me.

Comment: This worked with `Vitest` by changing `jest.fn` to `vi.fn`.

Answer (score 65):

I chose to add the polyfill as a dev dependency and add the following line to setupTests.js/ts:

```
global.ResizeObserver = require('resize-observer-polyfill')
```

Comment: Very slick, and worked perfectly. I like it! To get your types to match up nicely, swap it out for the `import` equivalent, and assign it in the next line.

Comment: Nice! I had to do `window.ResizeObserver = require...` but then it worked without an issue.

Comment: Simplest solution by far, this worked for my monorepo powered by nx.dev.

I did have to add into my jest.preset.js configuration (setupFilesAfterDev option with the value being the location to setupTests.js) as nx doesn't create setupTests.js file by default.

Comment: you made my day and my week!!!

Comment: i had to add `setupFiles: ['./setupTests.ts'],` to `jest.config.js` but then this worked too

Comment: ...that said, having successfully got the polyfill to rid me of errors, i subsequently discovered that `ResizeObserver` was returning widths and heights of `0` or `undefined` ... and so had to mock it anyway! (in a manner similar to @silveste answer below)

Comment: One liner helped after lot of efforts. That's was simplest solution. Thanks

Comment: This totally made my day, I only had to change it from `global.require...` to `window.require...` just like Alex Wally mentioned and it started working, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, quick and simple.

Comment: Simple and great answer, using NextJs 13 and SurveyJs I had to use:
`useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.ResizeObserver = require('resize-observer-polyfill').default
    }
}, [])`

Answer (score 40):

Mock the ResizeObserver:

```js
class ResizeObserver {
    observe() {
        // do nothing
    }
    unobserve() {
        // do nothing
    }
    disconnect() {
        // do nothing
    }
}

window.ResizeObserver = ResizeObserver;
export default ResizeObserver;
```

sample.test.js

```js
import ResizeObserver from './__mocks__/ResizeObserver';
import module from 'sample';

describe('module', ()=> {
     it('returns an instance of ResizeObserver', () => {
           // do something that uses the resize observer
           // NOTE: The actual observe handler would not be called in jsdom anyway as no resize would be triggered.
           // e.g.
           expect(module.somethingThatReturnAReference to the resize observer).toBeInstanceOf(ResizeObserver);
        });
});
```

<sub>[source](https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill/issues/50#issuecomment-488064120)</sub>

Comment: And how I ca test what's going on in the resizeObserver callback? For example, I have some changes to an HTML element style, that I need to test. How?

Comment: Yeah, I'm still clueless of how to now test any of the logic inside the ResizeObserver :(

Comment: I had to do this as my test says that it does not have `jest`

Answer (score 17):

Building upon the already excellent answers, here is what I did to get my React Testing library tests running

Take a dependency on the required polyfill in `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
  ...
}
```

Update the `setupTests.ts` file as follow.

```
import * as ResizeObserverModule from 'resize-observer-polyfill';

(global as any).ResizeObserver = ResizeObserverModule.default;
```

Now your tests should run fine.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't like any implementation that relies on something similar to an actual implementation. If we are going with integration testing, I'd join [RTL's opinion](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#unimplemented-parts-of-the-web-platform). I needed unit testing which would require isolation. The only way I could think of isolating this is mocking the `ResizeObserver`. So here is my take on it:

I've created a simple, dumb but externally adressable `FakeResizeObserver`. The process goes as follows:

1. Replace `window.ResizeObserver` with the `Fake` one
2. `setNextResizeObserverId` so that the `Fake` is addressable
3. Your actual code creates an instance of your `Fake` (without knowing it)
4. You can `triggerResizeObserver` from the test code

Additionally you have easy access to `resizeObserverInstances` if that's needed.

```
// FakeResizeObserver.ts
type ObserverId = string;

let nextObserverId: ObserverId | undefined;

export const setNextResizeObserverId = (observerId: ObserverId) => (nextObserverId = observerId);

const subjects: Record<ObserverId, HTMLElement[]> = {};

export const resizeObserverInstances: Record<ObserverId, FakeResizeObserver> = {};

export const triggerResizeObserver = (observerId: ObserverId, subjects: HTMLElement[]) =>
    resizeObserverInstances[observerId].trigger(subjects);

export default class FakeResizeObserver {
    id: ObserverId;
    callback: (entries: Array<{ target: HTMLElement }>) => unknown;

    constructor(callback: () => unknown) {
        if (typeof nextObserverId === 'undefined') {
            throw new Error(
                'Call setNextResizeObserverId before instantiating a FakeResizeObserver.'
            );
        }

        this.id = nextObserverId;
        nextObserverId = undefined;
        this.callback = callback;
        resizeObserverInstances[this.id] = this;
    }

    trigger(subjects: HTMLElement[]) {
        this.callback(subjects.map((target) => ({ target })));
    }

    observe(element: HTMLElement) {
        if (!subjects[this.id]) {
            subjects[this.id] = [];
        }
        subjects[this.id].push(element);
    }

    unobserve(element: HTMLElement) {
        delete subjects[this.id][subjects[this.id].indexOf(element)];
    }

    disconnect() {
        this.callback = () => undefined;
        delete subjects[this.id];
    }
}
```

And here is how a test could be implemented:

```
// useMyHook.test.ts
import React from 'react';
import FakeResizeObserver, {
    setNextResizeObserverId,
    triggerResizeObserver,
} from './FakeResizeObserver';
import useMyHook from './useMyHook';

describe(useMyHook, () => {
    
    // Replace the original observer with the Fake
    let originalResizeObserver: typeof ResizeObserver;
    beforeAll(() => {
        originalResizeObserver = window.ResizeObserver;
        window.ResizeObserver = FakeResizeObserver as any;
    });
    afterAll(() => {
        window.ResizeObserver = originalResizeObserver;
    });

    it('does some stuff', () => {
        // setNextResizeObserverId allows separate instances and access to them.
        setNextResizeObserverId('WHATEVER');

        const element = document.createElement('div');
        const getElementById = jest.spyOn(document, 'getElementById');
        getElementById.mockReturnValue(element);

        // Call the actual hook
        useMyHook();

        // !!! Act as if a change occured
        triggerResizeObserver('WHATEVER', [element]);
        
        // Hope you have something better to test.
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey rather than downloading a polyfill you can follow this approach

```
class ResizeObserver {
  constructor(observerCallback) {
    this.observerCallback = observerCallback;
  }

  observe = () => {
    // using actual dom element as mutation observer requires
    // an actual node in dom
    const scrollContainer = document.querySelector(
      '.horizontal-scroll-view__items',
    );
    // Mutation observer observer any changes in DOM tree
    const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
      mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
          this.observerCallback();
        }
      });
    });

    observer.observe(scrollContainer, { attributes: true });
  };
}

global.ResizeObserver = ResizeObserver;
```

With mutation observer you can hardcodingly resize your div and its attributes would be monitored with mutation observer. Hence it will result in callback trigger.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in my React project. I solved this problem by following these steps below.

1. `npm i -D resize-observer-polyfill`
2. `global.ResizeObserver = require("resize-observer-polyfill");` under the setupTests.ts

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the mock in `beforeEach` so I can test the calls to observer

```
  let MockObserverInstance: ResizeObserver;

  beforeEach(() => {
    MockObserverInstance = {
      observe: jest.fn(),
      unobserve: jest.fn(),
      disconnect: jest.fn(),
    };
    global.ResizeObserver = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => MockObserverInstance);
  });

  it('your test', () => {
    ...
    expect(MockObserverInstance.observe).toHaveBeenCalledWith(elem);
  });
```